# Can't get Sinatra's PUT method to work with an ERB form

Tags: forms, sinatra, erb, put

(I'm new to Sinatra)

I have, in my index.erb the following form:

```
<form method="post" action="play">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
  <input type="button" value="Next" name="next" id="next" title="Next" />
      ...
</form>
```

and in my app's file (play.rb) I have the following:

```
put '/play' do
  ...
  ...
end
```

the .erb is under app\views\ and play.rb is under \app.

For the life of me, I can't get the play to be invoked. I've even tried using a post too with no luck. Based on another question asked here, I've included use Rack::MethodOverride for the _method hack. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the button to:

```
<input type="submit" value="Next" name="next" id="next" title="Next" />
```

unless you bind the button to some javascript action.

Comment: Thanks! The key was changing the input type to submit. Phew.